# what practical option are avialble for scaling Windows executable

Tags: scaling

need advice about how to scale a cpu intensive tasks on desktop Windows. The system will not run any web server, it will run multiple and growing number of executable 
writing data to database(each to its own database but the same db server).
I was thinking of setting something like a cluster or grid based on blade servers, so I would just plugin a new blade and system would automatically expand utilizing new server's cpu . memory and disk but that seems to be out of my league as my skill level ends at setting up regular Linux/Windows networks and windows/web programming. I am using sql server but can move to any other db that runs on windows.

I actually  started coding so to speak master process which will continuously check when system needs to be expand by checking how many processes are running on each blade and remotely starting new process on a blade where resources are available using power shell.
Looks like the worst option but I have to make it work one way or another.

How else I can do this considering the fact that my runtime environment can be only desktop windows. (xp now and 7 later)?

Thank you, any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your making an application that's CPU intensive then I highly recommend using a language that utilizes a static compiler instead of a JiT compiler. The chart located here:

http://www.raulvm.com/information-systems.php/2010/12/09/interpreted-vs-compiled-languages

Which should be able to help you make a more informed decision.

Comment: thank you for reply, that is not option for me though, doing that using static compiler will be way too expensive for me and I am afraid the project will never see a day light.

Comment: @Vlad How so? You can get every language offered on that chart for free. Visual C++: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express GNU C++: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html Mono: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html ..... All Free. People (companies) really want you using their language and bragging about it.... a lot.

Comment: thank you Dave for your reply, i meant expensive in terms of time, which will translate into money after all but time is more important for me at this stage. Looks like something like HyperV and win 2008 can help me to scale this easier...